# Django CheckConstraint failing

Tags: django, constraints, check-constraints

I'm creating a custom user-model where every user needs a company assigned, unless they are a superuser or staff.

To accomplish this, I'm adding 3 CheckConstrains as seen below:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    '''
    Custom User class, username and email are required. 
    Company is required except for staff and super users
    '''
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(is_superuser=False, is_staff=False, company__isnull=False),
                name="user_must_have_company",
            ),
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(is_staff=True, company__isnull=True),
                name="staff_cannot_have_company",
            ),
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(is_superuser=True, company__isnull=True),
                name="superuser_cannot_have_company",
            ),
        ]
```

Desired behaviour is:

- Super-users and Staff users cannot have a company
- all 'normal' users need to have a company set.

However, all initial conditions fail on the same CheckConstraint `user_must_have_company`.

```
user = CustomUser.objects.create(username='staffuser', is_staff=True, company=None)
IntegrityError: CHECK constraint failed: user_must_have_company
```

```
company = Company.objects.create(name='Test')
user = CustomUser.objects.create(username='normal_user', is_staff=True, company=company)
IntegrityError: CHECK constraint failed: user_must_have_company
```

```
user = CustomUser.objects.create(username='superuser', is_superuser=True, company=None)
IntegrityError: CHECK constraint failed: user_must_have_company
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checks here say that a user needs to have `is_superuser=False`, and `is_staff=False`, and `company` should not be `None`/`NULL`, so this is not a *conditional* statement, it implies that the `is_superuser` should always be `False`. The next check contradicts this by saying that `is_staff` should be `True` and `company` should be `None`/`NULL`, and finally the last one says that `is_superuser` should be `True` and `company` should be `None`/`NULL`.

What you can do is to work with the *disjunctive form* of an *implication*. Indeed, in boolean logic, the expression *A → B* is equivalent to *¬A ∨ B*, so the condition (*A*) does not hold, or if it holds, its implication (*B*) should hold. This means that the checks are equivalent to:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # …

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(is_superuser=True)
                | Q(is_staff=True)
                | Q(company__isnull=False),
                name='user_must_have_company',
            ),
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(is_staff=False) | Q(company=None),
                name="staff_cannot_have_company",
            ),
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(is_superuser=False) | Q(company=None),
                name="superuser_cannot_have_company",
            ),
        ]
```

In this particular case however, we can simplify this to:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # …

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        constraints = [
            CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(is_superuser=False, is_staff=False) ^ Q(company=None),
                name='user_has_company_iff_no_staff_admin',
            ),
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you Willem. You're too kind for this world :)

Comment: By the way, may I ask, where did you find the docs on ^

Comment: @S.D.: here it talks about XOR: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q and there is a link to a guide to make more complex queries.